# Internal server error on delete - Contao

Tags: content-management-system, contao

I'm new to contao . I created a backend custom module . The listing of records is looking fine.But When I trying to delete or copy the record the system  returns internal server error.And also can't edit pre-saved records.Screenshots are attached below.Please help me.

```
// List
    'list' => array
    (
        'sorting' => array
        (
            'mode'                    => 1,
            'fields'                  => array('title'),
            'flag'                    => 1,
            'panelLayout'             => 'filter;search,limit'
        ),
        'label' => array
        (
            'fields'                  => array('title', 'teaser'),
            'format'                  => '%s <span style="color:#b3b3b3;padding-left:3px;">[%s]</span>'
        ),
        'global_operations' => array
        (
            'all' => array
            (
                'label'               => &$GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['MSC']['all'],
                'href'                => 'act=select',
                'class'               => 'header_edit_all',
                'attributes'          => 'onclick="Backend.getScrollOffset()" accesskey="e"'
            )
        ),
        'operations' => array
        (

            'editheader' => array
            (
                'label'               => &$GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['tl_solutions']['editheader'],
                'href'                => 'act=edit',
                'icon'                => 'edit.gif'
            ),
            'copy' => array
            (
                'label'               => &$GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['tl_solutions']['copy'],
                'href'                => 'act=copy',
                'icon'                => 'copy.gif'
            ),
            'delete' => array
            (
                'label'               => &$GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['tl_solutions']['delete'],
                'href'                => 'act=delete',
                'icon'                => 'delete.gif',
                'attributes'          => 'onclick="if(!confirm(\'' . $GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['MSC']['deleteConfirm'] . '\'))return false;Backend.getScrollOffset()"'
            ),
            'show' => array
            (
                'label'               => &$GLOBALS['TL_LANG']['tl_solutions']['show'],
                'href'                => 'act=show',
                'icon'                => 'show.gif'
            )
        )
    ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To get a more detailed stack trace you should use the `example.org/app_dev.php` entry point.

Comment: Why tablename mut not be empty error?? the url generated is localhost/web/contao?do=tl_my_solutions&act=delete&id=2&rt=L‌​0JxD1F4sZsr3SBF6BnnB‌​NlZ3ASG9O6bK0uXOkvpK‌​lQ&ref=qhrLDq5L

Comment: I don't know why. But as I already said, you should use the `app_dev.php` entry point to get a full stack trace.

Comment: ok I will try..

Comment: @fritzmg got the solution.empty array of ctable was set in my dca . that was te problem.I configured app-dev.php and traced the log.